# How to prove $f^{-1}(f(X)) = X$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose $X \subseteq A$. Will it always be true that $f^{-1}(f(X)) = X$?

I am try to prove this problem with either proofs or counterexamples. I have found a counterexample for $f^{-1}(f(X)) \subseteq X$, but I believe $x \subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$ is true. However, I'm struggle with how to write the proof. Could someone please explain/show me how to do this.

Comment: Can you give your counterexample explicitly, if you're having trouble writing the proof?

Comment: For my counter example...   Take A= {1,2}, B={1}, x={1}  f:A->B defined by f(1)=1 and f(2) =1 Then f(X) =f({1}) = {1} and f^-1f(x)=f^-1({1})= {1,2} which does not equal x

Comment: Is $A$ your domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've found a counterexample to $f^{-1} f(X) \subseteq X$, then you're done: in order to show that $f^{-1} f(X)$ need not necessarily be $X$, it is enough to show that it need not be contained in $X$. (You are correct to think that there is a counterexample.)

You gave the (correct) counterexample $A = \{ 1, 2\}, B = \{1\} = X$, and $f:A \to B$ by $f(1) = f(2) = 1$.

An example proof might read as follows:

> It is false that in general $f^{-1} f(X) = X$. Indeed, we show that it is not even true in general that $f^{-1} f(X) \subseteq X$.
>
> Take $A = \{ 1, 2\}, B = \{1\} = X$, and $f:A \to B$ by $f(1) = f(2) = 1$. Then $f(X) = \{1\}$, and $f^{-1} f(X) = f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{1,2\}$.
> So $f^{-1} f(X) \not = X$, and indeed $f^{-1} f(X) \not \subseteq X$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Write down what it means for an element $a$ of $A$ to be in $f^{-1}(Y)$, $Y$ a subset of the codomain of $f$. Then specialise to the case $Y=f(X)$.